# Error when trying to interpolate using SmoothSphereBivariateSpline(): "ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolate data, which is randomly scattered on the surface of a sphere, onto a regular longitude/latitude grid. I tried to do this with `SmoothSphereBivariateSpline()` from the `scipy.interpolate` package (see the code below).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothSphereBivariateSpline

#Define the input data and the original sampling points
NSamp = 2000
Theta = np.random.uniform(0,np.pi,NSamp)
Phi   = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi, NSamp)
Data  = np.ones(NSamp)

Interpolator = SmoothSphereBivariateSpline(Theta, Phi, Data, s=3.5)

#Prepare the grid to which the input shall be interpolated
NLon = 64
NLat = 32
GridPosLons = np.arange(NLon)/NLon * 2 * np.pi
GridPosLats = np.arange(NLat)/NLat * np.pi
LatsGrid, LonsGrid = np.meshgrid(GridPosLats, GridPosLons)
Lats = LatsGrid.ravel()
Lons = LonsGrid.ravel()

#Interpolate
Interpolator(Lats, Lons)
```

However, when I execute this code it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation of [`__call__` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.__call__) of SmoothSphereBivariateSpline, note the `grid` flag (some other interpolators have it too). If True, it's understood that you are entering one-dimensional arrays from which a grid is to be formed. This is the default value. But you already made a `meshgrid` from your one-dimensional arrays, so this default behavior doesn't work for your input.

Solution: use either

```
Interpolator(Lats, Lons, grid=False)
```

or, which is simpler and better:

```
Interpolator(GridPosLats, GridPosLons)
```

The latter will return the data in grid form (2D array), which makes more sense than the flattened data you would get with the first version.